# PostgreSQL copy from succeeds but fewer rows copied then lines in file

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have several large csv (tab delim) files I need to copy into one table. Each file is five million rows. The first two files copy just fine with all five million records. But on the the third I get missing data.

I only copy about 3.9 million instead of five million. There is no error. It runs just fine. But fewer rows copied then exist in the file.

I have reviewed the text files and indeed there are five million distinct rows in the text file.

So after a very manual trial and error process I found the the last row that wrote correctly (annoying the frame that didn't write was neither in the end or the beginign). It appears that perhaps their is an issue with a particular field. The field ends with the following string: ."' (this is period, double quote, single quote) I am using tab deliminted, but is it posible that postgress is reading this as some kind of special character? I think all of the subsequent rows may be writing into the that field for that row.

Just to add some more context -- the field in which the double quotes are throwing things off also happens to be an email field. So there a email with a typo in it and a double quote. Then 1.1 million rows later there is another email with a typo in it with a double quote. All the records between these two double quotes don't get written correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That is not surprising if you consider that a logical line in a CSV file can span more than one physical line:

```
1,a text,2019-11-24
2,"a text
that contains a newline",2020-04-01
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be what's happening here. There are actual records missing.

Comment: Well, without more details we cannot help. Try to locate the first missing line and the one before that. Examine these rows in the CSV file and in the database.

Comment: So after a very manual trial and error process I found the the last row that wrote correctly (annoying the frame that didn't write was neither in the end or the beginign). It appears that perhaps their is an issue with a particular field. The field ends with the following string:     ."'   (this is period, double quote, single quote)       I am using tab deliminted, but is it posible that postgress is reading this as some kind of special character? I think all of the subsequent rows may be writing into the that field for that row.

Comment: Yes so this is exactly what's happening. For some reason postgress is seeing the double quote (") as continuing the filed and it doesn't end the field until it sees the next double quote (") which in this case is 1.1 million rows later and it explains my missing 1.1 million rows. Postgres is writing all of that information into the one field.

Comment: Any advice on how to proceed? I would just delete all the erroneous double quotes in the file but even with a high quality text editor that is a tall order when working with 20 million plus records.

Comment: Oh, I also think the data in the field as something to do with it. In both cases where the double quotes threw things off they were in a field designed for email addresses. So the first one had a partial email and typo with a double quote, and the second offender had an email with a typo and double quotes inside. All the rows between these two rows (1.1 million) were not written correctly.

Comment: Great, that looks promising! If you need help, please [edit] the question and add a sample of the file conraining the problem line and the complete `COPY` statement you are using. Perhaps the file is not valid CSV.